# Time taken for transitioning between two activities

Tags: android, performance

I want to measure the time that is taken while transitioning from one activity to another in an Android app. How can I achieve this?

Comment: print current time in first actvity onStop/onDestroy and second activity onCreate, and get difference between both the time.

Comment: you can put a timer in the destroy of activity 1 and put the value in the intent, and in the activity 2, you get the time in onCreate or on Start methode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TIME", System.currentTimeMillis());
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in `SecondActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    long timeStart = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("TIME", 0L);
    Log.d("TAG", "Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the current time into the Intent extras.  The new activity should read that extra and figure out how long it took at the end of onResume (make sure to do this only the first time onResume is called).  I' assuming here you want to measure from starting the activity to it being fully loaded and ready for user input, if you have some other definition change where you're getting the time in the second activity.